# PHP Laravel relationship - makeVisible hidden variables

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel, and I started doing models (databases, relationships), and I've got a small problem.

Let's say I want to get data from a model *with relationship*:

```
$results = TheEpisode::orderBy('addDate', 'desc') ->take(20)->with('TheAuthor')->get();
```

Now, inside the model, we have the following settings for `TheAuthor` which is related to `TheEpisode`:

```
protected $visible = array('uid', 'userName');
```

Now let's say I want to make `TheAuthor` password visible, to do that I've tried the following (but it gives error):

```
  foreach($results as $result) {

    foreach ($result->TheAuthor as $author) {
      $author->makeVisible("password");
    }

  }
```

Is there someone which can help me to make the password visible temporary?

Comment: Change the order of your query. Move `->with()` to the beginning so it is `::with()`.

Comment: Why are you even using `$visible`? Are you hiding rest of the fields in your table? This strategy of making things visible/hidden is incorrect. Prefer `$hidden` for such purposes. Secondly, the password you will be getting here will be hash encrypted (if you have saved it that way ofcourse), do you really want it that way?

Comment: Also, is 'password' present in your `$hidden` variable? Because if its not, then try using `addVisible()` method.